# Como hacer para que una variable exista en ambito global dentro de un loop en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Me gustaria que la variable productId y productApiUrl existieran afuera tambien porque las quiero asignar a atributos de una clase, como podria hacerlo?

```
  for( const product of products) {
  
    let productId = product.productId;
    let productApiUrl = `https://gift.kakao.com/a/v1/products/${productId}`
    
    let req: RequestOptions = { productApiUrl, productId, label: handlerLabels.detail }; 
    
  }
```

yo se que ellas solo existen ahi adentro y nos accesibles desde afuera

Comment: puedes argumentar un poco mejor cual es el objetivo?, es decir cómo quieres usar esa variable después de la ejecución del loop?

Comment: mi objetivo es que de un json empiece a iterar y asigne la variable productId al id y ese id se lo pase en productApiUrl donde esta la variable, y luego esas dos variables sean asignadas a un atributo de un objeto, que se llama ItemModel.ItemCode para el id y itemUrl para la url

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una variable vacia y luego sobreescribirla, por ejemplo:

```
var product_id;

for( const product of products) {
    product_id = product.productId;
}
```

De esa forma ahora podrás hacer console.log() de product_id y se mostrará con el valor que sobre escribiste.

Ahora si son varios datos puedes guardarlos en forma de array, por ejemplo.

```
const products_ids = [];

for( const product of products) {
   products_ids.push( product.productId );
}
```

Comment: lo que quiero es que esa variable lo que tiene adentro asignarselo a un atributo de una clase, asi serviria?

Comment: Si, la variable a sobreescribir debería estar al inicio de todo, una vez sobre escrita puedes usar su valor para asignársela a una clase o puedes desde que obtienes el ID usarlo como clase usando algún método como classList.add() sin embargo se necesitan mas datos para entender tu contexto asi que dependera de ti como lo uses.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar `let` en vez de `var` porque `let` es block-scoped y no crea propiedades globales si se crea en un contexto global

Comment: mi objetivo es que de un json empiece a iterar y asigne la variable productId al id y ese id se lo pase en productApiUrl donde esta la variable, y luego esas dos variables sean asignadas a un atributo de un objeto, que se llama ItemModel.ItemCode para el id y itemUrl para la url @JefferzonBol

Comment: Tu pregunta fue si puedes usar la variable fuera del bucle, lo que mencionas queda fuera de esa pregunta, presiona editar y reestructura tu pregunta, te recomiendo leer [ask] y como hacer un [example]. También has pruebas por tu cuenta, no podemos ayudarte si no nos das el contexto completo.